# MySql event date limitation?

Tags: mysql, events

am trying to generate an event that delete a table in a DB

my idea is to make that to run every (saying hypotetically) 10 min for ever ( no end date)

but I get an error as following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `starts` and `ends` parameters of the [create event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) command are timestamps. Currently the [upper limit of timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) in mysql is `2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'`. You can't specify any ends after this point.

If you want the event to run "forever", then do not specify any `ends` (although I would be surprised if your application would run unchanged beyond 2038...)